# Google crawler finds robots.txt, but can't download it

Tags: search-engine, search-engine-bots

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this robots.txt?

http://bizup.cloudapp.net/robots.txt

The following is the error I get in Google Webmaster Tools:

```
Sitemap errors and warnings
Line    Status  Details
Errors  -   
Network unreachable: robots.txt unreachable
We were unable to crawl your Sitemap because we found a robots.txt file at the root of
your site but were unable to download it. Please ensure that it is accessible or remove
it completely.
```

Actually the link above is the mapping of a route that goes an action Robots. That action gets the file from the storage and returns the content as text/plain. Google says that they can't download the file. Is it because of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's reading robots.txt OK, but your robots.txt then claims that http://bizup.cloudapp.net/robots.txt is also the URL of your XML sitemap, when it's really http://bizup.cloudapp.net/sitemap.xml. The error seems to come from Google trying to parse robots.txt as an XML sitemap. You need to change your robots.txt to

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://bizup.cloudapp.net/sitemap.xml
```

**EDIT**

It actually goes a bit deeper than that, and Googlebot can't download any pages at all on your site. Here's the exception being returned when Googlebot requests either robots.txt or the homepage:

> **Cookieless Forms Authentication is not supported for this application.**
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cookieless Forms Authentication
>       is not supported for this application.

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Cookieless Forms Authentication is not supported for this application.]
AzureBright.MvcApplication.FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args) in C:\Projectos\AzureBrightWebRole\Global.asax.cs:129
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticate(FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e) +11336832
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +88
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +266
```

FormsAuthentication is trying to use cookieless mode because it recognises that Googlebot doesn't support cookies, but something in your FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate method is then throwing an exception because it doesn't want to accept cookieless authentication.

I think that the easiest way around that is to change the following in web.config, which stops FormsAuthentication from ever trying to use cookieless mode...

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies" ...>
    ...
```

Comment: now that looks like an answer! I makes all sense and I check it out now... +1

Comment: how do did manage to see the exception? I have been trying some so called Googlebot simulators, but that exception is not happening.

Comment: Some Googlebot simulators use the headers from an old version of Googlebot, and for some reason only the latest version causes this problem. Google's Webmaster Tools has a 'fetch as Googlebot' function in Labs which you can assume always matches the real Googlebot.

Once you know the right headers to send, Fiddler allows you to hand-craft a HTTP request and inspect the response, so I copied the request headers from Shaji's answer to see what came back. (http://www.fiddler2.com/)

Comment: Well it appears that it works now. The sitemap has been submitted in webmaster tools and in my google custom search engine on-demand. Thanks a lot! I believe the cookieless thing saved me hours of research!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem in a simple way: just by adding a robot.txt file (in the same directory as my index.html file), to allow all access. I had left it out, intending to allow all access that way -- but maybe Google Webmaster Tools then located another robot.txt controlled by my ISP?

So it seems that for some ISPs at least, you should have a robot.txt file even if you don't want to exclude any bots, just to prevent this possible glitch.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the script that is generating the robots.txt file. When GoogleBot is accessing the file it is getting `500 Internal Server Error`. Here are the results of the header check:

```
REQUESTING: http://bizup.cloudapp.net/robots.txt
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: 300
Accept:*/*
Host: bizup.cloudapp.net
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

SERVER RESPONSE: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 19 Aug 2010 16:52:09 GMT
Content-Length: 4228
Final Destination Page
```

You can test the headers here http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers/#Report

Comment: Yes, something was wrong. Stevemagson helped me with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem to get your robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: http://bizup.cloudapp.net/robots.txt
```

However isn't it performing a recursive robots.txt call?

A Sitemap is supposed to be a xml file, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps)

Comment: Yes, I already knew that, but it was a dummy error on my part. Thanks! 1+